# How to delete files in linux system after certain date/drive full in my C++ program?

Tags: c++, linux

Is there a piece of C++ code which allows me to delete files in a specific directory which is like 30 days old? or when the drive which stores them is full? Thanks!

Comment: You simply need to make a cronjob entry for running a script which does this for you on your desired time interval.

Answer (score 3):

See

- [`unlink`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/unlink.2.html) - to delete files
- [`stat`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) - to find out times
- [`readdir`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/readdir.2.html) - to list files

use [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) to run the program once a day.

Alternatively use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and avoid the hassle.

Comment: @Viad - why change the links, perhaps your preference. seems rather shallow.